# Filtered search on custom list view not working/showing nothing

Tags: android, listview, search, filter

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnQueryTextListener {

    ListView list ;
    ListAdapter listAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> listTest;
     String name;
     Uri uri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        listTest = new ArrayList<String>( );
        list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);



        Scanner(Environment.getRootDirectory()+"/");

         if(listTest.size() != 0)
            {
                listAdapter=new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),listTest);
                list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

                list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
                {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
                {

                     name = (String) ((TextView) view).getText();


                    view.setSelected(true);


                    uri = Uri.parse(listTest.get(position).toString());
                    File fl = new File(uri.toString());
                    deleteFile(uri.toString());
                    Log.e("msg", "deleted");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name+".apk"+" is deleted from internal storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    /*if(fl.exists())
                    {
                        fl.delete();
                        Log.e("msg", "deleted");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name+".apk"+" is deleted from internal storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }*/


                    list.setSelection(position);




                }});





            }




    }


      private void Scanner(String path) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            {
                try 
                {
                        File fl = new File(path);
                        File[] listOfFiles = fl.listFiles();              

                        for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles)
                         {
                            String s = listOfFile.getName();

                            if(s.endsWith(".apk"))
                            {


                            // store file name in listSoundNames
                            int pos = s.lastIndexOf(".");
                            if (pos > 0)
                            {
                              name = s.substring(0, pos);

                            }
                            listTest.add(name);

                            }


                            /////////////////////////////////
                            File f = new File(path+s+"/");
                            if (f.exists() && f.isDirectory()) {
                            Scanner(path+s+"/");
                            }
                            ////////////////////////////////


                        }



                }
            catch (Exception e) { }
            }

            }
     /* private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
      };
*/


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            // Inflate menu to add items to action bar if it is present.
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
            SearchManager searchManager =
                    (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            SearchView searchView =
                    (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
            searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                    searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));


          //Sets the hint text to display in the query text field
          searchView.setQueryHint("...");

           searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);


            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            listAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }

     /*  
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                //clear text filter so that list displays all items
                list.clearTextFilter();
                } else {
                // apply filter so that list displays only
                //matching child items
                //list.setFilterText(newText.toString());
                //listTest.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
                 //listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //list.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
                }
            listAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }


      */
}
```

ListAdapter.java

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

     private List<Item> filteredData;


    private Context _context;
    private List<String> list;
     ViewHolder holder=null;
        View row=null;
        private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;


        private List<Item> items;

    /*public  ListAdapter(Context _context,List<String> list,List<Item> items)
    {
        this._context=_context;
        this.list=list;
        this.items=items;

    }*/

        public  ListAdapter(Context _context,List<String> list)
        {
            this._context=_context;
            this.list=list;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(_context);

        }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }
     @Override

        public int getViewTypeCount() {

         return getCount();

        }

        @Override

        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

         return position;
        }

        private static class ViewHolder
        {
            public TextView textView;
            public ImageView imageThumbnail;


            public ViewHolder(View row) {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                 textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);





            }

        }




    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        row=convertView;
        holder=null;


       // Item i = items.get(position);
           try{


               if(row==null)
               {
                   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, viewGroup, false);
                   holder=new ViewHolder(row);
                     row.setTag(holder);
                     Log.d("newrow", "New row");

          /*/View row = convertView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, viewGroup, false);
            }


            TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);*/
            holder.textView.setText(list.get(position).toString());




          /* if(holder.imageThumbnail != null)
           {
               Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
               if(myBitmap != null)
                   holder.imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
           }*/


        /* bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);*/

           /*ContentResolver crThumb = getContentResolver();
           BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
           options.inSampleSize = 1;
           bmThumbnail = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, position, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);*/

               }
            else
            {

                 holder= (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
                 Log.d("recycle", "Recycling stuff");

            }
               }
               catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }


          /* try
           {
               if(row!=null)
               {
                   if(position==MP4.selected_item)
                   {
                     row.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       row.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                   }
               }
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {

           }
           */
            return row;

    }
    /*public Object getFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         return new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                    if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0) {
                        results.values = items;
                        results.count = items.size();
                    } else {
                        List<Item> filtered_items = new ArrayList<Item>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                            if (items.get(i).getText().toString().contains(charSequence))
                                filtered_items.add(items.get(i));
                        }

                        results.values = filtered_items;
                        results.count = filtered_items.size();
                    }

                    return results;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                    filteredData = (List<Item>) filterResults.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

         };
    }*/

    public Filter getFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         /*if (mFliter == null)
                mFliter = new CustomFilter();*/
            return mFilter;

    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();



            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

            String filterableString ;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i);
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(filterableString);
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredData = (List<Item>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

    }
```

I am trying to use filtered search on this list view, but while I type on the search, it returns nothing, but it should display the items that starts with or contains the letter I type in the listview. Listview does not update at all, and holds the items that are displayed in listview. What I am doing wrong and what should I do?

Comment: Giving a downvote without commenting is rude. May I know why it was downvoted?

Comment: Wait, how is that possible? When I load the app items are showing in the list view, then how can it be null? @0X0nosugar

Comment: That's allright, does my question deserve an upvote here?

Comment: Check out this example: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/06/01/create-searchview-filter-mode-listview-android/

Comment: Thank you a lot :) @0X0nosugar

Comment: Compare your code with this.

Comment: @activesince93 Yes I have already tried that at first but what I was getting is the layout over the listview which showing the typed letters, not updating the listview :(

Comment: @0X0nosugar I was also thinking the same, something is definitely wrong there, but what to do?

Comment: @0X0nosugar Can you show that code please? It would be really helpful